# Gradle 'PName' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio

iv'e lately installed android studio and unfortunately faced this problem when i try to create a project :
Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
what should i do

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Open android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib directory.
3. Delete all gradle-*-1.8 files
4. Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh.